# Перекрытие объектов CreateJS

Tags: javascript

Помогите закоренелому Flash-разработчику с переходом. Я создал в Animate сцену, раскидал всё по слоям - выглядит прекрасно, НО: кнопка на более нижних слоях реагирует, когда я вожу по верхнему.

Если в ходе выполнения программы я добавлю на слой, который выше этих кнопок другой MovieClip или Bitmap - он не перекрывает кнопки и они продолжают быть активными. Грубо говоря: чёрный экран, но в некоторых местах курсор становится "pointer" и обрабатываются события по нажатию

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 movie.cursor = 'default';
```

Добавляем по отношению к нужному MovieClip и всё отрабатывает как нужно!